# binary search parabola (c/c++)

Tags: c, algorithm, return-value, binary-search

I am trying to implement binary search to find the minimum in parabola and it appears to be correct, when I print the value just before returning it. Problem is that when I print the result of the function in the console or assign it to a variable the value is different.

My task here is: I have a sorted array and I need to find the element where |(ai – a1)–(aN – ai)| is minimal (If the array was cities, then I have to find the city that is closest to both the first and the last city).

To make this more simple I am just using static arrays

```
/*This is my sorted array: 1, 3, 6, 7, 11, 18, 20, 21, 22, 27, 30, 31, 32
And this here is the second array with the result of  |(ai – a1)–(aN – ai)|:
31, 27, 21, 19, 11, 3, 7, 9, 11, 21, 27, 29, 31*/



#include "stdafx.h"
int binary_parabola(int * arr, int l, int r) {
    //if (l > r) return -1;
    int k = (l + r) / 2;
    if (arr[k] <= arr[k + 1] && arr[k] <= arr[k - 1]) {
        printf("%d\n", k); //prints out 5
        return k;
        printf("I'll never get here\n");
    }
    if (arr[k] < arr[k + 1] && arr[k] > arr[k - 1]) binary_parabola(arr, l, k-1);
    if (arr[k] > arr[k + 1] && arr[k] < arr[k - 1]) binary_parabola(arr, k+1, r);
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 6, 7, 11, 18, 20, 21, 22, 27, 30, 31, 32 };
    int b[13];
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (a[i] - a[0]) - (a[12] - a[i]);
        if (b[i] < 0) b[i] *= -1;
        //printf("%d, ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int n = binary_parabola(b, 0, 13); //here I got 7, not 5
    printf("%d\n", n);
    //printf("%d\n", binary_parabola(b, 0, 13));
    return 0;
}
```

So the correct result from this task would be the index of the number 3 in my second array "b" which is 5 but it returns 7, the next value, while before return it prints 5 and I can't figure out why. It's probably something incredibly simple and I feel bad about asking but I can't make sense of this. If I assing "k" to a global variable before returning it, it has the correct value, I don't get it.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: Simple binary search requires sorted data.  Your parabola's data isn't sorted.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are two different languages.  The C++ language has `std::vector, std::sort and iterators`.  The C language doesn't.  You can pass arguments by reference in C++.  Pick one language tag.

Comment: You only return a value when you find the minimum; otherwise you recurse, but don't return anything. So if the minimum is found in a deeper recursion level, it returns the correct value to the higher recursion level, but there the value is discarded. Simply putting `return` before the recursive calls should fix this, by passing the return value up to the highest recursion level.

Comment: @m69 That did it! I knew I overlooked something so simple, thank you!